# Define requests that would not refresh user session

Tags: java, request, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have incoming requests from application and I don't want them to extend user session. Is it possible to exclude those requests or to not refresh session after they leave the session?

I see that now each request on leaveSession is refreshing it's expiry date.

I am using tapestry framework, in config I'm just getting ServletEnvironment and set SessionHandler with setMaxInactiveInterval

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your Session configuration details? (both the server level configuration, and the webapp specific configuration).   The solution might be a simple configuration change, or it might be something else.

Answer (score 0):

If your application (or your framework) is using `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` it will refresh the expiration date.

That's standard behavior for `HttpSession`, you access it, it refreshes.

The only way to not have it not refresh is to not access it.